# UIBarbuttonItem not calling action method

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am using this code to add a navigationbar button.

```
UIColor *green = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.7 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [KHFlatButton barButtonWithTitle:@"Go Pro!" backgroundColor:green];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action =@selector(goProButtonTapped);
```

Button shows up, but it doesn't call its action method.

```
- (void) goProButtonTapped
{
    NSLog(@"Go Pro button Tapped");
}
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

You should also set target:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target = self;
```

You can also create bar button item with custom view:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIColor *green = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.7 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
button.backgroundColor = green;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(goProButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Go Pro!" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Comment: Try to initialise button with target and action.

Comment: Don't work. Can you provide the code to add a navigationbar item button with background color and action method.

Comment: With this code Action gets called, but bg color doesn't show up. I ended up adding button background image.

Comment: You can try to use setBackgroundImage:forState: method.